# User Donations - ExpressJS, Angular 9

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal, stripe-payments, payment

Is there a simple way to implement where a user donates `x` and gets `isPremium = true` added to their account. Stripe documentation is confusing me, and I have not found any updated tutorials on this. It sounds like a simple concept, but seems to be a complex solution.

I am using an Express API, and Angular 9.

Please help...

Comment: Do Yuu have stripe in place at your website?. when a user goes and donates, stripe will send you a response against the donation, you can perform the further tasks accordingly.

Comment: You should be able to use [Webhook Notifications](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to receive events when payments are successful. Then, you process things on your own systems based on those events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments linked to [Webhook Notifications](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) for the stripe case

For PayPal there are similarly [Webhooks Events](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/), as well as the legacy [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/ipn/) service